# Split protobuf message to multiple output buffers

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

How can i split a protocol buffers message to multiple output buffers?

E.g. the ByteSize of the message is 20 and i have only a buffer of 10 bytes.
I want to write half of the message to this buffer, transfer it, and write the second half of the message to the buffer and transfer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement the [ZeroCopyOutputStream](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.io.zero_copy_stream#ZeroCopyOutputStream) interface; you can re-use a single fixed-size buffer, just writing the contents whenever `Next` is called. (You have to handle `Backup` too, for the final buffer.)